# PROXMOX rendomly reboots

Tags: linux, proxmox

I have a Proxmox cluster with two physical servers, pve and pve2.  They are identical Dell R710s with 96GB of memory and 1TB (RAID-10).  For some reason which I have yet to identify, pve2 will power cycle.  I have check HW logs through iDRAC and there are no alarms or errors.

I am fairly new to Proxmox so I don't know where to look for errors logs outside of the usual Linux places like *syslog* and *dmesg*.

Here is a snipet of my syslog when the reboot happened: (@ Dec 30 16:54:01)

```
Dec 30 16:50:00 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Dec 30 16:50:01 pve2 systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 16:50:01 pve2 systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Dec 30 16:51:00 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Dec 30 16:51:01 pve2 systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 16:51:01 pve2 systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Dec 30 16:52:00 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Dec 30 16:52:01 pve2 systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 16:52:01 pve2 systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Dec 30 16:53:00 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Dec 30 16:53:01 pve2 systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 16:53:01 pve2 systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Dec 30 16:54:00 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Dec 30 16:54:01 pve2 systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 16:54:01 pve2 systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 dmeventd[492]: dmeventd ready for processing.
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.73-1-pve (build@pve) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP PVE 5.4.73-1 (Mon, 16 Nov 2020 10:52:16 +0100) ()
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.73-1-pve root=/dev/mapper/pve-root ro quiet
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 systemd-modules-load[483]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bf378fff] usable
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bf379000-0x00000000bf38efff] reserved
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bf38f000-0x00000000bf3cdfff] ACPI data
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bf3ce000-0x00000000bfffffff] reserved
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000183fffffff] usable
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.6 present.
Dec 30 16:57:42 pve2 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: Dell Inc. PowerEdge R710/0Y7JM4, BIOS 6.3.0 07/24/2012
```

Any suggestions on what It may be or where I could check?

Answer (score 0):

It can be hardware failure, the most common one is faulty RAM.

Run a memtest on your server to find out.